# Visual Studio 2008 Constantly Freezes on Me

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

If this isn't the right place, please move as necessary.

This is REALLY affecting my production. I can't pinpoint when it started, but recently VS2008 has been freezing on me quite often. The freeze happens for 1-10 minutes. This seems to usually happen when I click into the source editor. The projects I am working on are ASP.NET MVC 2 projects with JavaScript and C# code.

I do have Office 2007 installed and I ran the repair that I found was suggested somewhere on the web component, but that didn't fix it.

My version for VS is 9.0.30729.1 SP.

On the plus side I get more web browsing in, but really hurts my groove when I am trying to get something done.

**Update**: I completely uninstalled then reinstalled VS 2008. The problem still exists. The problem most commonly happens when I am in the HTML editor. This app uses the AJAX toolkit, others use JavaScript/jQuery.

**Update 2**: `/safemode` doesn't fix it. I still say it has to be the JavaScript intellesense. How do you disable only the JavaScript portion of intellesense.

**Update 3**: I didn't have SP1 installed. I have installed that and will see what happens from there.

**Update 4**: SP1 didn't fix it. I am still working through the given answers thus far and seeing if anything fixes it. I'll keep this updated with any changes.

**Update 5**: I can't remember if I mentioned that everything else on my PC works fine while VS is locked up and Task Manager isn't showing anything that is pegged.

**Update 6**: I have been working all day in a WinForm project and had no freezes. So it is something with only web projects.

**Update 7**: Another developer started to work with ASP.NET MVC 2 and started having the same freezing problems. We think it might have to do with the MVC framework stuff. Anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution, but migrating the project(s) to Visual Studio 2010 fixes the problems.

Answer (score 2):

try to deactivate all addins that can cause troubles. I have, once, had some problems with resharper on X86 computes. The solution was quite big and the memory used by resharper was big enough to make the devenv.exe process growth up to the 2GB per process limit.

if it solves your problem, you will have to experiment reactivating one by one addin until you found the guilty one.

*[edit] continues from comments*

Other suggestions, try to run these command lines :

> devenv.exe /safemode

does it works better in safe mode ?

> devenv.exe /resetsettings
>
> devenv.exe /resetaddin
>
> devenv.exe /resetskippkgs

can also help... but you will loose your settings

Comment: I don't see any addons. I know I have GhostDoc, Visual SVN, and one other installed. These have been installed for months and only started to have problems recently.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get a message when it freezes?

I continually had it freeze up with the "Visual Studio is waiting for an operation to complete" message and the options "Switch To" or "Continue Waiting"- neither of which helped at all. There was no apparent pattern to when or why it occured.

You shouldn't have to wait 10 minutes for it to unfreeze. You should be able to stop the devenv.exe process in the task manager to force visual studio to close.

For me a corrupt installation of MZ-tools was the problem. If you're using that try uninstalling.

Comment: After a couple tries I can kill it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a virus scan and memory test?  One of my colleague was plaguing from same issue due to a faulty RAM stick.

Answer (score 1):

Several things to try:

- Checkout an entirely clean source tree, in case there's some disk corruption or strange permissions
- Create a new user account on the machine (or switch to one that exists already).  If it works ok there then that isolates it to something in your account -- either a process hook or permission problems
- Run [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) and disable anything that might be hooking into the process (check the AppInit_dlls tab in particular)
- Download the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009), run `windbg` and attach to the `devenv.exe` process once it's hung.  Break into the debugger and type `!analyze -v -hang`.  That may show you what it's waiting for, or if it's some 3rd party component that's causing the problem.

Comment: Any recommendation of debugging tools? I have never used one like that before. Just the one built into VS for debugging my applications.

Comment: I've added a link and amended the instructions.  `windbg` is a lot lower level than the Visual Studio debugger, but the `!analyze` command makes it hugely powerful for diagnosing both crash dumps and process hangs.

Comment: The new user profile didn't work. Trying clean source tree next.

Comment: New source tree didn't work and RAM checks out okay. Doing a hard drive check next.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I'm sure others can also be slow to upgrade compilers. A clean didn't work, but deleting the *.suo, *.ncb, and *.user file fixed the intellisense crashing VS2008 issue for me. Symptoms were that auto-complete was not always working (with an intellisense warning message in the status bar at the bottom), and sometimes a right click for context menu would cause it to hang, and I think it sometimes just hung spontaneously on background auto-backups.